# Saving a Line Chart into a SQL Database

Tags: c#, wpf, livecharts

So, I've been working on this one project that involves saving a line chart, capturing it, and redrawing it for comparison. The thing is I just don't know of an efficient way to save it. I am currently using a library called [Livecharts](https://lvcharts.net/) and I am using this [example](https://lvcharts.net/App/examples/v1/wpf/Constant%20Changes). I personally thought about saving each individual value, but feel like that would get too out of hand, considering there is going to be lots of lines charts that I will save. So my question is, does anyone know of a better way to save a line graph?

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: What do you want to compare? If you want to compare individual values, you need to store individual values. If you want to compare the images, you need to store them as blobs. "Out of hand" for a database means terabytes anyway. BTW all versions of SQL Server 2016 SP1 support columnstore indexes, compression and in-memory tables - even Express and LocalDB

Comment: How many points do you need to store? What kind of comparison do you want to perform? SQL Server can use windowing and calculate running sums, averages etc. so you may need to store all data just for that. If you add both columns to a clustered index you'll have fast range queries, windowing right away

Comment: The graph could potentially run for around 5 minutes. So all of the x, and y values. How many that could possibly be. As far as comparison, I am comparing drawn graphs.

Comment: The duration is meaningless without the *sampling frequency*. And monitoring systesm store multiple counters for days. You still haven't explained what kind of comparison you want. Could you just save the graphs as PNGs and diff the pictures? Or *add* them, so that both lines appear on the same graph? What would that accomplish?

Comment: Can't share those details. The graph is hooked up to some hardware, it outputs numbers, which is the Y axis. We want to compare them, and yes I'll put the previous graph points behind the current one that is being drawn.

Comment: OK, I have the answer but I can't share it either. Hint : I already answered both probable scenarios - statistical analysis or image comparison

Comment: Yes, I saw that, and I've been very aware of it. lol

Answer (score 1):

You could buid a serializable class, that holds the `ChartValues`

```
[Serializable]
public class ChartValues
{
    public DateTime time;
    public int Value;
}
```

Then save the XML serialized data in an SQL Table with an XML column and restore it like this:

```
foreach(ChartValue val in SavedChartValues)
{
ChartValues.Add(new MeasureModel
                {
                    DateTime = val.Time,
                    Value = val.Value
                });
}
```

Comment: Why XML? This isn't *more* efficient than storing the data in separate columns, it's quite the opposite

Comment: It is not more efficient (And it wasn't asked for efficient). But it is cleaner as a single chart would be represented by a single row. And Data that only needs to be touched in whole will be in a single column. Thats why I suggested it. Just out of curiosity would there be a case whe XML would be more efficient than any other solution?

Comment: The OP did ask for efficiency. XML is not cleaner in an way either - it's far more complex, takes far more space than any of the other ways to store complex data in a single *cell* - BLOBs, JSON, or even a SQLCLR type

Comment: The cleanest way - one that doesn't violate normal forms, is just to store the timeseries data as any other data. A table with a date and value field. That *does* allow querying, processing, indexing, It *doesn't* take any more space